# iHasApp - App Definitions Update

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, updates, url-scheme

Do you know how the App definitions in iHasApp are generated / can be updated?

It comes shipped with the following definitions;
https://github.com/danielamitay/iHasApp/blob/master/iHasApp/schemeApps.json

I have run this on  number of devices with differing Apps and there are some that are not detected that I am certain have a scheme / URL but are not present in the current definitions. If I manually add their AppID's into the .json, iHasApp detects them and displays the App in the results as expected.

I have considered mining all released AppIDs from the itunes API but this seems like a hefty time intensive process and would populate the json with >600k AppIDs that may not be configured to work as a scheme / URL.

How is the best, most thorough way to update this with working AppIDs and (if possible) Facebook ID's?